# How do I use DOMDocument's createElement to create a Javascript element?

Tags: php, html, domdocument

How do I go about using DOMDocument's `createElement` to create a new Javascript object in a document?

The best I have achieved so far is:

```
$node = $doc->createElement("script");
```

However, this outputs:

```
<script></script>
```

What I am looking to output is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Why? The `type` attribute is redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `->setAttribute` method after creating the node:

```
$node->setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
```